# Sending low level raw HTTP/HTTPS requests in node JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, ssl, https

I am in the process of writing an intercepting proxy tool like [Burpsuite](https://portswigger.net/burp) for security testing. An important part of that would be sending malformed HTTP requests in the case of which we would have to give the user full control over the request!

So, I can't have complete control while using a library! I need to be able to send raw HTTP requests to the target hosts like,

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
```

#### My attempt :-

I tried using the node JS [net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), and I was able to connect to host on port 80 (*HTTP*), and while connecting to port 443 (*HTTPS*), a connection is established but returns an empty response!

On some researching, I found out that this has something to do with SSL, as I tried telnet and it too failed for *HTTPS* connections and by looking at some stackoverflow answers!

Is there any option through which I can directly send raw HTTP/HTTPS requests directly from my node application?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the [``tls``](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback) module for HTTPS requests.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delayed response, but I have a partially working code where I am not able to make HTTP requests using the TLS module but able to make HTTPs requests!

Comment: That's correct, actually--the ``net`` module is unencrypted TCP, and the ``tls`` module is encrypted TCP (i.e. TLS). You must use both modules to make HTTP/HTTPS requests: ``net`` for HTTP, and ``tls`` for HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module [http-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-tag), which allow writing literal http messages like -

```js
const net = require('net')
const HTTPTag = require('http-tag')

const socket = net.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
}, () => {
    // This callback is run once, when socket connected

    // Instead of manually writing like this:
    // socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n')
    // socket.write('My-Custom-Header: Header1\r\n\r\n')
    
    // You will be able to write your request(or response) like this:
    const xHeader = 'Header1' // here in the epressions you can pass any characters you want
    socket.write(
        HTTPTag`
        GET / HTTP/1.1
        My-Custom-Header: ${xHeader}
        
        `
    )
    socket.end()
})

socket.on('close', hasError => console.log(`Socket Closed, hasError: ${hasError}`))

// set readable stream encoding
socket.setEncoding('utf-8')
socket.on('data', data => console.log(data))
```

Regarding TLS, currently i am in research on built-in node modules, and I haven’t view the tls yet.

Comment: Hey! But my requirement is to send raw requests to a remote server, but I am unable to identify from the library on how to do that. I think if you can ellaborate more the `socket` object that you have used, I'll get a little more understanding :)

Comment: My answer relates to a part of sending malformed http requests, when you want a control of what you are sending, in the end, regardless what Transport Layer Protocol you are using - TCP or TLS over TCP, you will need this, if you haven't already something like this. I will edit the answer to provide information on how to open a socket and send request, you can test it on express server.

Comment: Wow, this is an excellent solution ✨!

I am currently able to send HTTP requests and receive their responses, and I would like to know if there is a similar way to make HTTPS requests? I tried using the TLS module but I get a self signed certificate error when I connect to google.com. Here is the code https://pastebin.com/TKgARX9V! Any thoughts? :)

Comment: I currently set `servername: 'google.com'` in options, and it works, You can find it in docs - [tls.connect](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback)
If i not misinterpret the idea behind, is that, sometimes there are multiple hostnames served under the same server, so this option specify which hosts certificate your client expects. Same is written in docs - [Server Name Indication](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_alpn_and_sni)

Comment: Well, All the same, I misinterpreted the `servername` option :) Here is a note from docs - **It can be used by a multi-homed server to choose the correct certificate to present to the client**, it used by the server, not by the client :)